# Bluetooth audio suddenly not functional

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth-speaker

Using 16.04. Did today's update (12/8/16) and suddenly my bluetooth speaker isn't working (an Amazon Echo). Not low volume - no sound at all. The Echo works fine from other devices. I have a Lenovo t410 laptop.

UPDATE: I just tried removing the Echo from my list of bluetooth devices. I paired it again, but still no audio.